# I'm getting error that i'm missing a reference but which one?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I added to the top of the form

```
using mshtml;

IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webbrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
            IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)doc.body).createControlRange();
```

The error is on:

```
(IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)doc.body).createControlRange();
```

Error   3   One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?

Comment: Are any of the types underlined in the IDE?  If you google the type names, you should get a link to MSDN that will tell you what assembly the object is in.

Comment: The solution was to add Microsoft.CSharp as reference once added this dll it's all working. Not sure why i needed it.  I missed this error i had too 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported and once added the csharp dll it's all fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do remember that just by adding the statement `Using mshtml;` (considering that all the types used falls under `mshtml` dll) will not bring in the referenced dll. You will also need to add the reference of the dll to your project `Reference` folder.

Make sure you have done that.

Comment: I did i added it from this directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.mshtml.dll maybe it's the wrong dll? After added it i did the using mshtml; but still getting this error.

Comment: Yes, right click on your project Reference folder -> add reference -> from .NET tab add the dll you want.

Comment: @FalconsMyman, is it a COM dll? how did you obtained that dll?

Comment: @Rahul mshtml is part of .net framework. i just tried adding it. it works fine and the code compiles as well. wonder why it's not working for the op.

Comment: Rahul from this directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.mshtml.dll i saw it in another stackoverflow answer for using the IHTMLDocument2 since first time IHTMLDocument2 wasn't exist then after adding this dll now it's finding and using the IHTMLDocument2 but giving me this error.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ, NO that's wrong. It's not part of core .NET framework rather it's a office interop assembly (COM assembly). Check MSDN.

Comment: @FalconsMyman, check this post once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068159/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-mshtml-strong-name-validation-fai

Comment: @Rahul Oh, yes sorry. I meant that it's not an external library. Although MS Office assemblies are external... whatever.. my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to the `Microsoft.mshtml` assembly. Follow these steps to do so:

- Project → Add Reference
- Go to the Extensions tab (under Assemblies) on the left
- Make sure the checkbox next to `Microsoft.mshtml` is checked.
- Press OK.

Now everything should work fine.

<sub>You may see more than one entry for `Microsoft.mshtml` in the listed assemblies. In that case select any one of them</sub> <sup>(preferably the newest version).</sup>

Comment: Tried now again same error. Before i added the dll file from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.mshtml.dll and got the error now i tried as you said i saw one Microsoft.mshtml.dll added it and still same error.

Comment: did you try my steps above? don't add the dll directly. use the reference adder (..kind of) dialog box as in the answer.

Comment: Farhan i tried your way too. I saw there one Microsoft.mshtml added it but still same error.

Comment: @FalconsMyman I would guess you forgot the checkbox. make sure it's checked. only highlighting and pressing ok won't do