# Could not load file or assembly of Microsoft.mshtml error in application

Tags: c#

I've created an window application. When i installed it on another PC for testing it gives me following error:

> could not load file or assembly 'Miscrosoft.mshtml Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral..'

Why my set program files are not picking up `Microsoft.mshtml.dll` from my bin folder.

I gave proper reference and already set `copy local` property of reference

Comment: Take a look at [this like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068159/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-mshtml-strong-name-validation-fai), it may help

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set property of my  reference as **Embed Interop Types=True** and it works on another PC anyway.